# How to safely deep-dive into objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

So I'm working my way through Typescript...step by step. Just getting myself into generics and deep-diving into object structures by building generic constructs and such.

I believe I'm making progress (hopefully) but at times...it feels very hacky the way I'm implementing things.

Is there a better way of doing the below or is this expected?

type.ts

```
export type Options<A> = {
    platform?: keyof A;
    type?: unknown;
    name?: unknown;
}
```

init.ts

```
import { ProjectType, plate } from './.dep.ts';
import * as InitType from './type.ts';

export const init: ProjectType.Command<InitType.Options<typeof plate>> = {
    desc: 'Init',
    exec: ({
        platform = 'platform',
        type = 'type',
        name = 'name'
    }) => {

        const plt = plate[platform];
        const typ = plt[type as keyof typeof plt];
        const result = typ[name as keyof typeof typ];

        console.log('Le Result', result);
    }
}
```

Also if anyone has any...more readable resources for Typescript guidance/troubleshooting please provide. I find the official docs quite a pain to read.

Comment: Could you describe the issue you're trying to solve, and [not the approach you see fit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) of solving this issue? TypeScript is not a hacky language - but it has restrictions, and is definitely not a golden hammer one-size-fit-all kind of solutions.

Comment: This is more of a question around an implementation/type safety rather than an actual problem that is occurring. The above implementation works but I'm wondering how "type safe" it actually is.

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your title please? It seems to not be what you're actually asking and it smells very dangerously close to "opinion based" territory for me (which would be a reason to close the question). I *think* there's an actual question in there, but you'd need to edit the title to make it more visible.

Comment: Good point, have changed the title. Hopefully it's more question based now rather than opinion based.